# Jquery jscrollpane ajax content not loading in pane object

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I have been fighting with jScrollPane - v2.0.0beta11 - 2011-07-04 and Jquery 1.7.1.

I am using an ajax call to populate a div with content.
In the old jscrollpane, one would simply load the content via ajax and then upon success, apply the jscollpane method to the div. Now as I understand it, you need to initialise the object by calling the method on the div and then load your content into the pane object instead of the div as it has been altered by jscrollpane.

I am doing this, but the content is not loading.

```
//initialise jscrollpane on page load

   $(document).ready(function() { 
   api = $('#functionsWindow').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
   }

   //ajax script
   function ajaxFromLink(page,querystring,target){

   theTarget = document.getElementById(target);
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: page,
   data: querystring,   
   success: function(msg){  
        if (theTarget != ''){
            if(theTarget.id == 'functionsWindow'){
                api.getContentPane().html(msg);
                api.reinitialise(); 
                console.log('api method: ' + msg);
            }else{
                console.log('normal method: ' + msg);
                $(theTarget).html(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

This line api.getContentPane().html(msg); is not inserting the content. I can confirm that the content is being passed back from the server.

If I do not initialise the jscrollpane onLoad and do it within the first ajax call instead, the scroll bar will work. Subsequent ajax posts will not work however. I do not know what I am missing. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Define `api` variable in the global scope it should work fine. Try this

```
    var api;

    $(document).ready(function() { 
       api = $('#functionsWindow').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
    });

    //ajax script
    function ajaxFromLink(page,querystring,target){

       theTarget = document.getElementById(target);
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: page,
       data: querystring,   
       success: function(msg){  
            if (theTarget != ''){
                if(theTarget.id == 'functionsWindow'){
                    api.getContentPane().html(msg);
                    api.reinitialise(); 
                    console.log('api method: ' + msg);
                }else{
                    console.log('normal method: ' + msg);
                    $(theTarget).html(msg);
                }
            }
        }

       });
     }
```

Comment: You are definitely doing something wrong. Where are you calling ajaxFromLink?

Comment: Still getting the same problem. The server is returning the proper data but it just is not being inserted in the div. In fact all of the jscrollpane divs go missing as well from the original target div.

Comment: I'm calling ajax from link a button.

Comment: Boy am I dumb, but this may help someone!
At some point I had a $('functionsWindow').empty(); which when called creates the problem.
I suppose one should perform api.getContentPane().empty(); instead.